# How we can add container for inner pages in magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2.2.6

How we can add container for inner page template not in home page in magento 2.2.6?

Comment: can you please more elaborate your question little more that what exactly you want so that someone can help you in better way!

Comment: Please check this screenshot "http://prntscr.com/lbn3iu" . how to design this ? please let me know.

Comment: i want to add container class in inner pages layout template...

Comment: inner pages, means only cms pages ? and which layout are you using also do you have separate page-layout for home page? 1column, 2columns-left, 2columns-right

Comment: i am using for home page "custom-home" layout and for inner pages 1column.

Comment: Extened the cms_index_index.xml in your theme 
`app/design/frontend/vandor/theme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

and add the remove tag to remove the particular block/referenceBlock/referenceContainer from Home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add / update your **main.content** container in default.xml file with code below, it will add two divs **container-inner-a** and  **container-inner-b** after main container.:

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content">
    <container name="container-inner-a" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">
         <container name="container-inner-b" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
            <container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row" name="div-content-row">
                <container name="columns" />
            </container>
         </container>
     </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

This is how you need to update you layout file and change div names / numbers as required.

**NOTE :** this will add additional div on all page / layout. For home page you can get that page css class and change its width accordingly.

Comment: i apply this code but this also applied on our home page "http://prntscr.com/lbne4h"

Comment: yes this will add on all pages, for home page you can add css class to change width . check your page body there you will find class "cms-index-index", using that class change width of home page. otherwise you have to edit all layout files and add this code.

Comment: Please can you explain in detail. on home page our body class"http://prntscr.com/lbnh88"  and for inner pages "http://prntscr.com/lbniwd".

Comment: for example , newly added div class is "container-inner-a" and you are on home page. so your home page body class added is "cms-index-index" then my home page css would be .cms-index-index .container-inner-a container { width : 100% } to give 100% width on home page.

Answer (score 0):

To write custom HTML into your magento **CMS-Pages** Just do follow the below given steps.

- Just go to **`Admin(Back-end) > CONTENT > Elements > Pages`**.
- Click on add new page or if you want to edit already existing page click on select > Edit (Please refer [this image](https://www.screencast.com/t/EnDbL32pvYK)).
- In that page go to **`Content > Click on Show / Hide Editor`** to get the HTML editor section instead of the way wysiwyg editor (Please refer [this image](https://www.screencast.com/t/FIcrMfFr)).
- Now you can write your HTML code here into this section (Please refer [this image](https://www.screencast.com/t/1sWuS7Sgz5QL))
- To write **`css`** for this page you can write **`css`** into your default **`css`** of your **`theme`**
- Do click on save button after making your changes there in the back-end & check the front-end for the changes done. If not getting the changes you made there on the front-end, then flush your cache.

For that you can do it from your back-end & also by executing the command from your terminal just run the below command from your terminal.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thank You!

Comment: i know this method but i want to add by code in all products detail page and other pages..

Comment: Are you working with CMS pages or with the product details page?

Comment: i am working both pages

Comment: This answer is for the CMS pages only, what changes you want in your product details page?

That's why I told you to elaborate your question with proper steps you taken with some screenshots so that someone can help you better with the thing that you are looking for!